# list a combination of 3 numbers in 6 different ways?

Tags: r, permutation

From a range of numbers from 001 to 999, I would like to be able to formulate a function where from 001 to 199, the combinations of numbers will be listed in up to 6 different ways. Example 192 as 192, 129, 291, 219, 912, 921. The listing should obviously begin with 001 which will show as: 001, 010, 100.

Comment: You're asking about permutations. You might want to look at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/permutations/index.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what format you want the results in.

As commented, these are permutations: `combinat::permn` is probably the most convenient way to achieve this.

Format a number with zero-padding (`"%03d"`), split into characters (`strsplit(.,"")`):

```
f0 <- function(x) strsplit(sprintf("%03d",x),"")[[1]]
```

Create all permutations, squash them back into strings (`paste/collapse`), and select the unique values (e.g. `000` has only one unique value)

```
f1 <- function(x) unique(sapply(combinat::permn(f0(x)),paste,collapse=""))
```

Apply to each of the integers

```
result <- lapply(0:999,f1)

head(result)
[[1]]
[1] "000"

[[2]]
[1] "001" "010" "100"

[[3]]
[1] "002" "020" "200"

[[4]]
[1] "003" "030" "300"

[[5]]
[1] "004" "040" "400"

[[6]]
[1] "005" "050" "500"
```

Later values do indeed have up to six entries.

Answer (score 1):

You could make vectors of indices with `tidyr::crossing` or `expand.grid`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

indices <- crossing(x = 1:3, y = 1:3, z = 1:3) %>% 
    filter(x != y, x != z, y != z) %>% 
    pmap(~unname(c(...)))

indices %>% str
#> List of 6
#>  $ : int [1:3] 1 2 3
#>  $ : int [1:3] 1 3 2
#>  $ : int [1:3] 2 1 3
#>  $ : int [1:3] 2 3 1
#>  $ : int [1:3] 3 1 2
#>  $ : int [1:3] 3 2 1
```

...which you can then use to subset each input vector as you iterate across them:

```r
perms <- pmap(crossing(x = 0:9, y = 0:9, z = 0:9), function(...){
    map_chr(indices, function(x) paste(c(...)[x], collapse = "")) %>% 
        unique()
})

perms[500:510] %>% str(vec.len = 6)
#> List of 11
#>  $ : chr [1:3] "499" "949" "994"
#>  $ : chr [1:3] "500" "050" "005"
#>  $ : chr [1:6] "501" "510" "051" "015" "150" "105"
#>  $ : chr [1:6] "502" "520" "052" "025" "250" "205"
#>  $ : chr [1:6] "503" "530" "053" "035" "350" "305"
#>  $ : chr [1:6] "504" "540" "054" "045" "450" "405"
#>  $ : chr [1:3] "505" "550" "055"
#>  $ : chr [1:6] "506" "560" "056" "065" "650" "605"
#>  $ : chr [1:6] "507" "570" "057" "075" "750" "705"
#>  $ : chr [1:6] "508" "580" "058" "085" "850" "805"
#>  $ : chr [1:6] "509" "590" "059" "095" "950" "905"
```

This ultimately is still a lot of iteration, so while it works fast enough for 6000 iterations, a vectorized approach would scale better.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that gives the desired output with no duplication and no additional calls to clean up duplicate results. We take advantage of `std::next_permutation` from the the algorithm library in `C++`, which takes a vector as input and generates lexicographical permutations until the first permutation is reached. This means, we only generate 3 permutations for `001`, 1 permutation for `999`, and 6 permutation for `123`.

We start by generating all combinations of `as.character(0:9)` of length 3 with repetition by utilizing `gtools::combinations`.

```
## install.packages("gtools")
myCombs <- gtools::combinations(10, 3, as.character(0:9), repeats.allowed = TRUE)

nrow(myCombs)
[1] 220
```

Here is an `Rcpp` version that exposes `std::next_permutation` to `R`:

```
## install.packages("Rcpp")

Rcpp::cppFunction(
    "CharacterVector permuteDigits(CharacterVector v) {
        std::string myStr;
        std::vector<std::string> result;

        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
            myStr += v[i];

        do {
            result.push_back(myStr);
        } while(std::next_permutation(myStr.begin(), myStr.end()));

        return wrap(result);
    }"
)
```

And finally, we bring it altogether with `lapply`:

```
permutedCombs <- lapply(1:nrow(myCombs), function(x) {
    permuteDigits(myCombs[x, ])
})
```

Here is some sample output:

```
permutedCombs[1:5]
[[1]]
[1] "000"

[[2]]
[1] "001" "010" "100"

[[3]]
[1] "002" "020" "200"

[[4]]
[1] "003" "030" "300"

[[5]]
[1] "004" "040" "400"

permutedCombs[151:155]
[[1]]
[1] "356" "365" "536" "563" "635" "653"

[[2]]
[1] "357" "375" "537" "573" "735" "753"

[[3]]
[1] "358" "385" "538" "583" "835" "853"

[[4]]
[1] "359" "395" "539" "593" "935" "953"

[[5]]
[1] "366" "636" "663"
```

And here is proof that we have all 1000 results with no duplications:

```
sum(lengths(permutedCombs))
[1] 1000

identical(sort(as.integer(do.call(c, permutedCombs))), 0:999)
[1] TRUE
```